# PostgreSQL 13 Partition Global Indexing Strategies

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-partitioning, postgresql-13

Based on my research so far, I understand that it is not possible to create an out-of-the-box global index across partitions in PostgreSQL 13.

Are there any alternative strategies that can facilitate the requirement of a global index across partitions?

Greatly appreciate any resource references on the topic.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no simple, cheap and reliable way to guarantee uniqueness of a column that is not the partitioning key.  The only option is a trigger, but [that requires that you use `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/).

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for the information. I'll check it out the option you suggested.